# Creating Table using Data from another Table (ReactJS + State)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, use-state, react-table

Update: Is the problem with how I print out rows with rows.map? rows is an array so that should work right?

0: {date: '12/31/2021', id: 1, name: 'button', price: '10'}
1: {date: '12/31/2021', id: 2, name: 'turner', price: '11'}
length: 2

I'm trying to write a program that given a table of lessons can find the balance (total money) each student should pay and insert that data into another table (rows) using react state. My code should loop through the lessons table (starting at index 0), check if the student name is already in the balance table (rows), if yes add the price of the lesson to their current balance, if no create a new row and add the student to the table initializing their balance as whatever the price was for their lesson.

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

function handleBalance(index, priceval)
    {
        setRows([index]['balance'] += parseInt(priceval));
    }

function handleAdd(nameval, balanceval)
    {
        setRows([
            ...rows,
            {
                name: nameval,
                balance: balanceval
            },
        ]);
    }

    const calculateBalances = () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < lessons.length; i++)
        {
            if((lessons[i]['price'])==="")
            {
                console.log("EMPTY ROW")
                continue
            }
            else{
                    const index =  rows.findIndex( (element) => element.name === lessons[i]['name']);
                    /*If name found in lesson table add price of lesson to current balance*/
                    if(index!= -1)
                    {
                        handleBalance(index, lessons[i]['price'])                        
                    /*If not found add new student by adding a row and setting initial balance as the price of the lesson*/
                    else if(index == -1)
                    {
                        handleAdd(lessons[i]['name'], lessons[i]['price']);
                    }
                }
        }            
    }
```

I am currently using the following code to output the table

```
<TableBody>
        {/*maybe the above functions are correct and im printing wrong*/}
      {rows.map((row) => {
          return (
        <TableRow
          key={row.name}
          sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
        >
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.name}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.balance}
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
         );
        })}
    </TableBody>
```

My output is currently this
[ turner 11]

But the output should be ("1." and "2." only there to represent new lines but not actually outputted)

1. Button 10
2. Turner 11

Thank you!

Comment: When updating state in react you need to use the set function provide by useState. Like you do in the handleAdd function. So add a handleBalance function which uses setRows instead of rows[index]['balance'] += parseInt(((lessons[i]['price'])))

Comment: Thank you for this! Nonetheless, currently it doesn't enter the handleBalance portion as the names in the table are different

Comment: did you fix this?